# How to customize redirect url after request validation fails in laravel 5?

Tags: php, forms, http, laravel-5, redirect

I am using `use Illuminate\Http\Request` to access form request. For example if my form request is coming from `http://localhost:8012/test_project/public` after validating it is automatically redirecting to `http://localhost:8012/test_project/public` with error messages but i want it to redirect to `http://localhost:8012/test_project/public#myform` because my form is visible in `#myform` section. So how can we do it. I am using Laravel 5.0
Following is my method code in controller that handles my request

```
public function add_user(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|min:3',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'mobile' => 'required|regex:/^[789]\d{9}+$/|unique:users,mobile',
            'pass' => 'required|min:6',
            'cpass' => 'required|same:pass'

         ]);

        $user = new Myuser;

        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->mobile = $request->input('mobile');
        $user->pass = md5("EEE".$request->input('pass'));
        $user->register_on = date('Y-m-d');
        $user->user_type = 'Free';
        $user->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $user->status = 'Active';

        $user->save();
        $insertedId = $user->sno;

        $uid = "UID".$insertedId;

        Myuser::where('sno', $insertedId)
          ->update(['uid' => $uid]);

        //echo $insertedId;
        return redirect('')->with('message', 'Registered Successfully');
    }
```

Comment: what does your code look like? You should be able to do something like `return redirect('/test_project/public#myform')->withInput();`

Comment: @BrianGlaz actually it is automatically redirect to previous `url`, even we use `redirect` method. It is not considering it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show some sample code.

Comment: @BrianGlaz i added my code

Answer (score 0):

If you make your own `Validator` instead of using `$this->validate()`, you can have more control over what happens on a failed validation. Here is an example from the laravel documentation. Make sure you add `use Validator;` to the top of your php file. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('post/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }

        // Store the blog post...
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i came to know about this but i am searching for any possibility of customizing previous url redirection using `$this->validate()`.